# Meaning of "constitution" in strange context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following passage is from the first chapter of Emily Brontë's *Wuthering Heights* (1847):

> He’ll love and hate, equally under cover, and esteem it a species of impertinence to be loved or hated again—No, I’m running on too fast—I bestow my own attributes over-liberally on him. Mr. Heathcliff may have entirely dissimilar reasons for keeping his hand out of the way when he meets a would-be acquaintance, to those which actuate me. **Let me hope my constitution is almost peculiar: my dear mother used to say I should never have a comfortable home; and only last summer I proved myself perfectly unworthy of one.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

The text then goes on to describe the previous summer, wherein the narrator displays timidity, thus unintentionally snubbing someone he loved.

What is the meaning of *constitution* in this sentence? I've looked at the OED for *constitution, n.*, and the definitions seem to include the following:

- the action of constituting
- a decree or law, or the action of effecting such a decree
- composition; the way something is made up (its constituency, if you will)
- physical nature and temperament

None of these definitions appear to readily fit the passage. Could someone define the word in context and explain what the sentence means?

Comment: I want to believe that the legal term "constitution" was conjured to reflect the fundamental/elemental make-up and characteristics of the laws of the country, just as the "constitution" of a person or organisation would reflect the fundamental elements that constitute their characteristics and behaviour - which should be the common ancestral meaning of all other/derivative meanings of the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's the last option you listed.  Without a little more context of the passage it's hard to know what exactly it's in reference to.

It used to be commonly used in reference to somebody's character.

Comment: Added more context; see my edit. Does *peculiar* here mean "different from that of Mr. Heathcliff"? If so, then how does *almost* fit in?

Comment: With more context I would say my initial feeling was correct.  It seems to me like this is from an old passage.  Back then peculiar was often used as a derogatory statement.  So it means she was bordering on might be considered "too different", but still within acceptable the range.

Comment: *Peculiar* just meant, as it does now, very unusual. Whether that was an insult or not depended on the wider context. One would hope that one had a peculiar constitution in conditions where one would deem a normal constitution unable to cope.

Answer (score 1):

Definition #4 you have listed is the meaning of 'constitution' in the quotation you posted. The girl in the sentence his hoping that her trouble in finding happiness is a result of a peculiar physical makeup and temperament rather than something psychological.

Comment: There's no girl in Mr. Lockwood's sentence (Mr. Lockwood is the  narrator at this point early in [the novel](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/768/768-h/768-h.htm)), aside from his “dear mother”.

Comment: @jwpat7 while correct, I think this has little impact on the meaning of the word.

Comment: @WChargin, true, there's no impact on the meaning  of *constitution*; but I'm unwilling to upvote an answer with this error.